# Rest Query correct but YQL doesn't pull data

Tags: jquery, json, xpath, yql

I have found sample code but my modifications are not getting any results. The sample code works and is found at [Puppy Tweets](https://gist.github.com/ydn/320156/raw/d0d9c76a71f284daa421040ac37c09fdd058023b/gistfile1.htm)

This is the way I've modified it and I get no results:

```
<script>
function handleResponse (json) {
    var results = json.query.results.json.results,
        ul = document.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0],
        li = null;
    for ( var i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {
        li = document.createElement( 'li' );
        li.innerHTML = results[i].text;
        ul.appendChild( li );
    }
}
</script>
<script src="select * from html where url="http://www.fishingnotes.com/lakeinfo.php?id=38742" and xpath='//div[@class="lbox"]/div[1]/div/span[1]'"></script>
```

I've used the YQL Console to verify the Rest Query is correct. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main mistake is trying to use (only) a YQL query as the source of a JavaScript script.  This needs to be a *URL*, which can be provided for you by the YQL console as highlighted below.

[image: Location of rest query URL in YQL console]

So the `<script>` element might look like:

```
<script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fishingnotes.com%2Flakeinfo.php%3Fid%3D38742%22%20and%20xpath%3D'%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40class%3D%22lbox%22%5D%2Fdiv%5B1%5D%2Fdiv%2Fspan%5B1%5D'&callback=handleResponse"></script>
```

There are also a couple of minor issues with the JavaScript itself. A basic working version might look like:

```
<script>
function handleResponse (json) {
    var ul = document.getElementsByTagName( 'ul' )[0],
        li = null;
    for ( var i = 0; i < json.query.count; i++ ) {
        li = document.createElement( 'li' );
        li.innerHTML = json.results[i];
        ul.appendChild( li );
    }
}
</script>
```

See [» this example on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/oqodal/2/edit).

Comment: Most awesome. Thank you so very much! I was beginning to lose hope.

Answer (score 0):

> script src="select * from html where url="http://www.fishingnotes.com/lakeinfo.php?id=38742" and xpath='//div[@class="lbox"]/div[1]/div/span[1]'">

Untested, but it looks like there are problems with the nested quotes here, so first change `url="http://www.fishingnotes.com/lakeinfo.php?id=38742"` to `url='http://www.fishingnotes.com/lakeinfo.php?id=38742'`.  Then there are quotes within quotes within quotes in your xpath, and I'm not sure it's possible to handle that inline.

Try storing `"lbox"` in a variable and refer to the variable instead of quoting directly.